# Trying to get variable to display as whole number

Tags: javascript, variables, math, addition, subtraction

Trying to get the variable "totalreq" to display as a whole number. I've tried a number of examples of math floor math round etc. At this point it breaks if i even remove the toFixed(2) that I added. Anyone have any Ideas for me?

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
$('#calc').keyup(function()
{   
//Calculate part A by adding
    var totala = parseInt($('#mortgages').val()) + parseInt($('#loans').val())          + parseInt($('#expenses').val());
    $('#resulta').text("$" + totala);
//Calculate the complex b1 
    var percentageincome = (70 / 100);
    var tvf = $('#timevaluefactor').val();
    var totalreq = parseInt($('#bgross').val()) * (percentageincome) * (tvf);
    $('#line4result').text("$" + (totalreq.toFixed(2)));
//add b1 to b2)
    var totalb = parseInt($('#efund').val()) + parseInt($('#childcare').val()) + parseInt($('#education').val()) + (totalreq);
    $('#resultb').text("$" + totalb);
//calculate c by adding
    var totalc = parseInt($('#cash').val()) + parseInt($('#stock').val()) + parseInt($('#estate').val()) + parseInt($('#business').val()) + parseInt($('#insloans').val()) + parseInt($('#totalbenefit').val()) + parseInt($('#otherdb').val());
    $('#resultc').text("$" + totalc);
//a + b - c = result
    var finalresult = parseInt(totala) + parseInt(totalb) - parseInt(totalc);
    $('#result').text("$" + finalresult);

});
```

});

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't used toFixed(0)? `var a = 3*0.2*6; a.toFixed(0);` a=4 (it rounds up as it's 3.6). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Could you define "breaks". Do you always get 0, does the console show an exception?
What happens if you log the value (either an alert or to console) just before you try to set the text?

Comment: Based on what im trying to do one example is 5 x .70 x 8.53 = 29.855 on my calc... Its supposed to be an estimate for life insurance so whole rounded dollars is the most detailed i would want it. 

e.g. 29.855 = $29 etc. 


I tried 0 but my var isnt always going to have the same # of decimal places because of the odd math goin on. It didnt seem to work when trying (0) for toFixed

Comment: OK, I made half of it work using toFixed(0)

But when part b2 runs the calculation it feeds a 0 infront of the answer... is this what dougis means? 

eg if I input 5 for #gross i get totreq=30 which is fine but for totalb = 029.85

Comment: Got IT! used Math.round on the second portion ( totalb ) 

Here my soloution, thanks dudes. 

var percentageincome = (70 / 100);
  var tvf = $('#timevaluefactor').val();
  var totalreq = parseInt($('#bgross').val()) * (percentageincome) * (tvf);
  $('#line4result').text("$" + (totalreq.toFixed(0)));
//add b1 to b2)
  var totalb = parseInt($('#efund').val()) + parseInt($('#childcare').val()) + parseInt($('#education').val()) + Math.round(totalreq);